# split a column into severals and covert them into one row in r

Tags: r, data.table, sqldf, subset

plz help me how to code to get the outcome below from the data.. i have a data frame containing more than 1000000 rows with nonconsecutive NA in it. i want to split TA_DAY column into like this: "1~5th,6~10th....continue..end" until the last row,  and combine them like the one below...  does anyone have an idea or tip?  which function? should i use for it?  thank u so much in advance G-day...

```
for(i in 0:161){
  aa[i+1]<-melt(dt4$WSmax[1:12+(12*i)])
}

list <- unlist(aa, recursive = FALSE)
df <- do.call("rbind", aa)




 ID YEAR PRICE                                    this is the one that i need 
    --------------                                  -------------------                          
    A  2001 19.45                                   19.45 98.23 12.33
    A  2003 98.23                                    NA   77.4  32.33
    B  2009 12.33               =>           
    C  2001  NA
    C  2004 77.4
    D  1999 32.33
    .
    .
```

Comment: I commented on your earlier post to show the dataset using `dput`.  It is unclear after reading the description `1~5th`, `6~10th..` In the expected output, you were rbinding PRICE 1 and 4, 2 and 5 etc...

Comment: thanks for your comment ...i just know about the dput function by reading your comment..

Comment: No problem.  The `dput` output is the one I pasted in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sapply(1:(nrow(dat)-3), function(i) dat$PRICE[c(i, i+3)])
 #      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
 #[1,] 19.45 98.23 12.33
 #[2,]    NA 77.40 32.33
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D"), YEAR = c(2001L, 
2003L, 2009L, 2001L, 2004L, 1999L), PRICE = c(19.45, 98.23, 12.33, 
NA, 77.4, 32.33)), .Names = c("ID", "YEAR", "PRICE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely clear on what is wanted since the description does not seem consistent with the sample output. I am assuming that all columns except `PRICE` can be ignored and we want each value of `PRICE` along with the value 3 positions ahead of it as that gives the sample output shown.  In that case `rollapply` from zoo can do it.  Here are two different ways:

```
library(zoo)

t(rollapply(dat$PRICE, 4, function(x) c(x[1], x[4])))
##       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
## [1,] 19.45 98.23 12.33
## [2,]    NA 77.40 32.33
```

Another way to do it with rollapply:

```
t(rollapply(dat$PRICE, list(c(0, 3)), identity))
##       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
## [1,] 19.45 98.23 12.33
## [2,]    NA 77.40 32.33
```